# Can `std::basic_string::operator[]` return a "distant" protected page nul terminator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, stdstring, c++17

So, `operator[]` does not directly say that `s[s.size()]` must be the character after `s[s.size()-1]` in memory.  It seems worded to avoid making that claim.

But `s.data()` states that `s.data()+k == &s[k]`, and `s.data()` must return a pointer.

Ignoring the seeming standard defect of using `&` on `CharT` above and not `std::addressof`, is the implementation free to return a different `CharT` (say, one on a protected page, or in ROM) for `s[s.size()]` prior to the first call to `s.data()`?  (Clearly it could arrange the buffer to end on a read-only page with a zero on it; I'm talking about a different situation)

To be explicit:

As far as I can tell, if `s.data()` is never called (and the compiler can prove it), then `s[s.size()]` need not be contiguous with the rest of the buffer.

Can `std::addressof(s[s.size()])` *change* after a call to `s.data()` and the implementation be standards-compliant (so long as `s.data()+k == &s[k]` has `.data()` evaluated before `[]`, but the compiler is free to enforce that).  Or are there immutability requirements I cannot see?

Comment: cppreference clearly says that since C++11 `operator[]` behaves exactly like you describe for `data().` However, it also mentions that this character can not be modified.

Comment: @SergeyA The wording above is my reading of the (current draft) standard, rather than based off someone else's (whomever edited cppreference last, say) interpretation.  If you want, I can add direct quotes, but they are not hard to find (open your standard, search for `basic_string`, jump to it from the index, search for `operator[` and `data(` from there).  I am wondering if there are *other* restrictions I missed (like I initially missed the `.data()` implied restriction on `&s[s.size()]`).  Most of the obvious ones (based off iterators) don't apply, as `*s.end()` remains UB.

Comment: Does the standard actually state that `s[s.size()]` is well defined and not UB? It is past the end of the string after all, and would be UB for any other container. As a practical matter every implementation is likely to hold the terminating null required by `c_str()` so it's probably a moot point.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes it does, in the definition of `operator[]`.  It must return a `CharT` reference (const or not depending) whose value equals `CharT()`.  Modifying it is UB.  It is thoughts about protecting that nul terminator that led to the above question.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, std::string is required to be stored in contiguous memory. This is the quote from the C++11 standard (section 24.4.1.4):

> The char-like objects in a
>   basic_string
>   object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any
>   basic_string
>   object
>   s
>   , the identity
>   &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n
>   shall hold for all values of
>   n
>   such that
>   0
>   <= n < s.size()
>   .

This quote about the return value of operator[] states that it returns the same as `&*(s.begin()+n)` (section 21.4.5.1):

> *(begin() + pos)
>   if
>   pos < size()
>   . Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type
>   charT
>   with value
>   charT()
>   , where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior

Then we have this quote on the return value of data() in (section 24.4.7.1):

> A pointer
>   p
>   such that
>   p + i == &operator[](i)
>   for each
>   i
>   in
>   [0,size()]
>   .

So data returns the same as you would get using the &operator[]. And any value between you retrieve using the &operator should be stored contiguously. So you can conclude both return a pointer to contiguous memory. So it will not return a pointer to a distance page.

Note that this only applies to C++11. Such guarantees were not made by the standard before C++11.

Comment: It should be fixed now.

Comment: Your first and second quotes specifically exclude the case where `n == s.size()` or `pos == size()`.

Comment: @Yakk: The part of the second quote supporting the claim that `operator[]` returns a reference to `*(s.begin()+n)` excludes the case where `n == s.size()`.

Comment: I see no guarantee that calls to `[s.size()]` return a stable location.  The only requirement above seems to be that once you call `data()` it must return one-past-the-end; prior to that, I see no restriction.  Which disagrees with your conclusion?